# powershell skript doesn´t work - but why - hang data behind the first line

Tags: powershell

Good day,

with the script below I would like to use the following input txt from my output txt.

Input:

```
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345678;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE999999;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777779;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE777777987;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777779765;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE77777797634;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777779763465;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE77777797623435435;
```

Output:

```
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;DE12345678;DE999999;DE7777777;DE7777779;DE777777987;DE7777779765;DE77777797634;DE7777779763465;DE77777797623435435;
```

The script takes the last value from the following lines and appends them to the first line at the end and adds semicolons:

```
Import-Csv input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..20)
1..9 | %{$data[0].($_+10) = $data[$_].10}
($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ";" -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' | out-file output.txt
gc test_neu.txt
```

if i save this into a .ps1 file it doesn´t work. anyone could say me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't assign Import-Csv to anything. The first line should be: `$data = Import-Csv input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..20)`  Your last line should be `gc output.txt`.  And use the dot notation to location the input.txt file in the current directory. With these fixes, your script works:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..20)
1..9 | %{$data[0].($_+10) = $data[$_].10}
($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ";" -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' | out-file output.txt
gc output.txt
```

Comment: a little question at the end, my target file now contains special characters like question marks. How can I change this?

Comment: @Julius `Out-File` takes an `-Encoding` parameter

Comment: the input file has the ansi encoding

Comment: As @MathiasR.Jessen says, try different `-Encoding` values on `Out-File`. The question marks are characters that weren't encoded properly (or rather, weren't understood by a given encoding). Since all the characters come from the input file, it seems the two files are not encoded the same.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to do what you want. [*grin*] it expects that the source lines are *all* to be combined.

i presume you can handle saving things to a file, so i leave that to you.

what it does ...

- fakes reading in a text file
  when ready to work with real data, replace the entire `#region/#endregion` block with a call to `Get-Content`.
- iterates thru the collection by index number
- if the line is the 1st, set `$NewString` to that entire value
- else, add the last data item of the line to the existing `$NewString` value with a trailing `;`
  the `.Where({$_})` filters out any blank items.
- display the string

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345678;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE999999;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777779;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE777777987;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777779765;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE77777797634;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777779763465;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE77777797623435435;
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

foreach ($Index in 0..$InStuff.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
    if ($Index -eq 0)
        {
        $NewString = $InStuff[$Index]
        }
        else
        {
        $NewString += $InStuff[$Index].Split(';').Where({$_})[-1] + ';'
        }
    }

$NewString
```

output ...

```
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;DE12345678;DE999999;DE7777777;DE7777779;DE777777987;DE7777779765;DE77777797634;DE7777779763465;DE77777797623435435;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but how can I save this into a .ps1 file to execute?

Comment: @Julius - copy it, paste it into the ISE, run it to test that it works in your setup. then change the `fake reading in a text file ` stuff to load your source file & confirm that it works with your real data. last, save it to a file with whatever name you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you don't know how many lines there are going to be on the input file:

```
$fmt='$1$2'
gc .\input.txt | %{$_ -replace '(^.*;)(.*;$)',$fmt;$fmt='$2'} | sc output.txt -NoNewline
gc output.txt
```

Comment: The lines are fixend, but I try to change the Script to work with up to 15 lines and Semikolons, do you have an Idea?

Comment: @Julius this should work for any number of input lines, and if you want to change `;` to another delimiter you just have to replace the two times it shows up in the second line. For example to use `¥` as a delimiter: change `'(^.*;)(.*;$)'` to `'(^.*¥)(.*¥$)'`

Comment: do you have an Idea, how could I change my script so, that I used for up to 15 lines?

Comment: @Julius 9 to 14 and 20 to 25 as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61958269/4496560 should get you there; however this version is line count indifferent so that when your friend changes his mind on the number of input lines next week or a year from now you don't have to come back and modify the script