# powershell script adjustment for desired result

Tags: powershell

Good day,

I need your help again. With the following script:

```
$data = Import-Csv .\input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..20)
1..9 | %{$data[0].($_+10) = $data[$_].10}
($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ";" -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' | out-file output.txt
gc output.txt
```

... I am editing a .txt file, which so far contains up to 10 data lines, where he writes the last value from the following lines into the first line.

If there are no 10 lines / values, he fills them with semicolons so that the file can be imported again later.

Now I would like to extend the script so that I could have up to 15 lines in the .txt file.

Can someone help me and tell me which parameters I have to adjust to get the desired result?

Input:

```
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345678;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE999999;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345678;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE999999;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE999999;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777778;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE999999;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777777;
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE7777778;
```

desired output:

```
Klaus;Müller;Straße;PLZ;Ort;;;;;DE12345;DE12345678;DE999999;DE7777777;DE12345;DE12345678;DE999999;DE7777777;DE999999;DE7777777;DE7777778;DE7777777;DE999999;DE7777777;DE7777778;
```

Unfortunately I don't know which values I have to adjust...

Comment: You want 15 lines in the output file, but your "desired output" is only a single line?

Comment: the script works with up to 10 lines of data in one input file. I would like to use it with up to 15 lines.

Comment: For the quick fix, change 9 to 14; however you may want to rewrite so that whatever number of lines come in get sent out...

Comment: It doesn‘t work if I change 9 to 14.... do you have an other idea?

Comment: also change 20 on the first line to 25

Comment: This script is an example of doing some unusual clever things and it makes it a bit "opaque".  You'd be better off in the long run with a script that more explicitly loops over items and creates a result clearly. But I can tell you what modifications to make now for this one. Change the 9 to 14 as @Gregor-y says, and also change the (1..20) to (1..25).  This -Header value creates additional columns in the input that's read in, into which the next statement places its results. A bit too clever for its own good I would say. But it will work if you make both these changes.

Comment: what about the current "15 lines" idea does not work with the answer given in your previous post on this subject? >>> powershell skript doesn´t work - but why - hang data behind the first line - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955861/powershell-skript-doesn%c2%b4t-work-but-why-hang-data-behind-the-first-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend **1..20** in the first line to **1..25**
and **1..9** in the second line to **1..14**

**Solution one**

```
$data = Import-Csv .\input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..25)
1..14 | %{$data[0].($_+10) = $data[$_].10}
($data[0] | convertto-csv -delimiter ";" -NoType | select -skip 1) -replace '"' | out-file output.txt
gc output.txt
```

But I would suggest another solution which is not dependend on the number of rows alltogether:

**suggested solution**

```
$data = Import-Csv .\input.txt -delimiter ";" -Header (1..20)
($data | 
 foreach `
   -begin {$Columns=(1..10)} `
   -process { 
     $Row = $_;  #Save the loop-variable
     $Columns.foreach({$Row.$_}) ;
   $Columns =@(10)} ) -join ";"
```

*Explanation*

In the first row the *$Columns-Variable* is set to array 1..10.
Therefore *$Columns.foreach({$Row.$_}* will produce all ten values of the first row. After that *$Columns* is set to Column 10 only. So for all Rows

Regards, Martin